# Files glob patterns specified did not match any files

Tags: node.js, npm, stylelint

i have problems. when i run : `npm run stylelint` . my cmd show notication

```
moutain-mental-website@0.0.0 stylelint E:\Mountain_Mental
> stylelint 'public/css/**/*.scss'

Error: Files glob patterns specified did not match any files
    at E:\Mountain_Mental\node_modules\stylelint\dist\standalone.js:83:19
```

Answer (score 6):

Try double-quotes:

```
> stylelint "public/css/**/*.scss"
```

Comment: @stevemao Commonly in shell languages, double-quotes allow for expansion/interpolation of special characters, whilst single-quotes provide literal strings if you want to avoid expansion (i.e., you literally mean the `*` character). http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about it after I left the comment :) But why passing literal `*` characters would work in Mac and Linux but not Windows? I thought that the literal string would pass to `node-glob`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @stevemao Windows limits more special characters than Mac and Linux for file paths. Maybe this is inherent of `node-glob` too, but I'm not sure. See here for a more comprehensive answer http://serverfault.com/a/150744/355340

Comment: So this only occurs on windows then :O as I'm using `"lint-styles": "stylelint './src/**/*.css'",` and this doesn't fail normally